# How to call this view entrypoint

Tags: views, entrypoint

So I read the TzKT documentation regarding this (https://netezos.dev/docs/call-view-entrypoints.html) and I understood most of it, but I'm trying to do it with Taquito. But I'm fairly new to this and I can't figure out how to call a more complex view entrypoint like this one:

```
(pair %snapshot
                    (pair
                      (contract %callback (pair
                                           (pair (int %num1)
                                                 (int %num2))
                                           (int %num3)))
                      (int %paramX))
                    (int %paramY)))
```

How can I call this entrypoint by submitting the 2 parameters I need (paramX and paramY) in order to get all the values I want (num1, num2 and num 3).

Preferably in python or js/ts, I just need one example and I can pretty much go from there.

Sorry if it is a basic question, it is just hard to find more complex examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Taquito, this should be helpful: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/lambda_view/.

From what I can read, it would probably look like this:

```
Tezos.contract
  .at('KT1...')
  .then((contract) => {
    return contract.views
      .snapshot([{ paramX: '0', paramY: '1' }])
      .read();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    println(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  })
  .catch((error) => println(`Error: ${error} ${JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}`));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!